# MongoDB C# Driver Unable to Find by Object ID?

Tags: c#, mongodb, nosql

Using MongoDB C# driver (http://github.com/samus/mongodb-csharp), seems that I'm unable to get the data by ObjectId. Below the command that I'm using:

```
var spec = new Document { { "_id", id } };
var doc = mc.FindOne(spec);
```

I also tried this:

```
var spec = new Document { { "_id", "ObjectId(\"" + id + "\")" } };
var doc = mc.FindOne(spec);
```

Both return nothing. Meanwhile, if I query it from the mongo console, it returns the expected result.

My question is, does that driver actually support the lookup by ObjectId?

Thanks..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It does support fetching by object ID.  Your id variable should be an Oid.  Is it the correct type?

Here is a complete program that will

- Connect to Mongo
- Insert a document
- Fetch the document back using its ID
- Print the document's details.

```
// Connect to Mongo
Mongo db = new Mongo();
db.Connect();

// Insert a test document
var insertDoc = new Document { { "name", "my document" } };
db["database"]["collection"].Insert(insertDoc);

// Extract the ID from the inserted document, stripping the enclosing quotes
string idString = insertDoc["_id"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");

// Get an Oid from the ID string
Oid id = new Oid(idString);

// Create a document with the ID we want to find
var queryDoc = new Document { { "_id", id } };

// Query the db for a document with the required ID 
var resultDoc = db["database"]["collection"].FindOne(queryDoc);
db.Disconnect();

// Print the name of the document to prove it worked
Console.WriteLine(resultDoc["name"].ToString());
```

Comment: @Ant: can you please elaborate? 

Do you mean, something like this?
var spec = new Document { { "Oid", id } };

Comment: is this using official driver or Norm?

Comment: This is the Samus driver, which was the only C# driver around when the question was asked.  It's mentioned in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
var spec = new Document { { "_id", ObjectId.Parse(id) } }; 

var doc = mc.FindOne(spec);
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?